# Adding callbacks to an animation queue - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I need to synchronize functionality with various animations... unfortunately jQuery queues up ONLY animations of a certain object.

jQuery offers the possibility to add callbacks, but I cannot pass it any external variables.

---

**Here is some code!!! =)**

```
var unicorn_actions = [...];
for( var i=0; i<unicorn_actions.length; i++){
    var unicorn_action = unicorn_actions[i];
    if(unicorn_action['type'] == 'movement'){
         $('#unicorn').animate({...}, unicorn_action['time']);
    }
    else if(unicorn_action['type']=='action'){
         $('#unicorn').animate({}, 0, function(){
               // I NEED TO APPEND THE ACTION TO THE ANIMATION
               perform_action(unicorn_action);
         });
    }
}
```

---

**1st problem**

```
var unicorn_name = "George";
$(...).animate({'top':100,'left':100 }, 100, function(){
    alert(unicorn_name);
})
```

This returns **unicorn_name undefined!**

---

**2nd problem**

If i need to append a callback to an animation queue I'm thinking of doing the following

```
$(...).animate({'top':100,'left':100 }, 0, function(){
    // my actions
})
```

**This messes up the animations...**

---

Any ideas guys? =)

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to do... but your first problem should not alert undefined... is there any other thing there that was not mentioned?

Comment: @Reigel: I need to access the value within the function

Comment: could you show more codes? you could try pasting it here http://jsfiddle.net/ if it's that long... with simple example, the alert works http://jsfiddle.net/vgQqd/

Comment: @Reigel thanks for that!! =) I added some code to the question!!

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do either. By declaring your variable as a var outside the scope of your callback, you should definitely be able to access the variable. The code example that Reigel posted shows this...

Comment: [Here is my jsfiddle guys =)](http://jsfiddle.net/r7MgY/1322/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version of your code that fixes all the issues you posted:

```
var actions = [
    {action:'movement', top:123, left:123, time:1000},
    {action:'alert', content:'test'},
];

$(function(){
    $.each(actions, function(i, action) {
        switch(action.action) {
           case 'movement':
                $('#unicorn').animate({top:action.top, left:action.left}, action.time);
                break;
            case 'alert':
                $('#unicorn').delay(50).queue(function(){ alert(action.content); });
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/cX3Ye/), there were several fixes in these changes:

- You were accessing the variable from an array, `i` changes by the time you used it...you need to pass it into a closure, which [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) creates.
- Since you don't need to animate to the *same* spot again, to add a callback to the queue just use [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) for the 50ms pause and [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) to add your function (or remove the [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) if you were just playing with it).
- Other minor improvements:

  - Changed your `if`/`else if` structure to a [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/switch), since it looks likely you'll add more cases.
  - Changed all of your `['prop']` to `.prop`...that's me just finding it easier to read :)
    ​